# Indent Guide plugin is not available anymore for Eclipse Photon 2018?

Tags: eclipse, github, eclipse-plugin, indentation

Is there a new plugin for guide Indention in Eclipse ?
As we know, this link from Github https://sschaef.github.io/IndentGuide/update provides us Indention Guide for Eclipse but it doesn't work anymore.
**Question is : Is there a new plugin for guide Indention in Eclipse ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fork of the initial plugin available here: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/indent-guide.

If you don't find it in the Eclipse plugin manager, one other way to install it is to drag and drop the "Install" button into your Eclipse window.

Tested on Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search reveals there is no obvious replacement plugin available. However, a fork of the original Git repository for the IndentGuide plugin has been upload to Github.

https://github.com/kiritsuku/IndentGuide